# combine upper tri and lower tri matrices into a single data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I wish to represent p values and distances as lower triangular and upper triangular entries in a single matrix. While I managed to create a UT or LT matrix for both, I have ben unable to merge them into a single data frame in R.

```
dist[(upper.tri(dist,diag=FALSE))]=0  #upper tri of distances
pval[(lower.tri(pval,diag=FALSE))]=0  #lower tri of p-values
```

I tried the following line but does not work

```
dist[(upper.tri(dist,diag=FALSE))]=pval[(lower.tri(pval,diag=FALSE))]
```

Any possible way of doing this?

Comment: How do you want to merge? Please give a sample of dist and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this could be done more elegantly, but I think this does what you want:

```
a <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
b <- matrix(1, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

a[upper.tri(a)]
b[lower.tri(b)]

new <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
new[upper.tri(new)] <- a[upper.tri(a)]
new[lower.tri(new)] <- b[lower.tri(b)]
new
```

Since you did not supply a reproducible example, I can't be sure, but basically I just take the upper and lower of matrices (one of 0s and the other of 1s) and combine them in `new`.  As proof of concept, new has 0s above the diagonal, 1s below, and NAs on the diagonal itself. Hopefully this gives you some insight into your issue.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for but much of the lines I was writing were clumsy. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 2):

Though, this question already answered I would like to add the following code for future use for anybody.

First, create two matrices of 10 by 10, with 1s and 2s only. Then using the package Matrix get only the lower and upper triangular matrices. Since there are no overlaps, we can simply use addition to combine the two matrices. Then convert the "dgeMatrix" first into a matrix and then to a data frame.

```
a <- matrix(1,10,10)
b <- matrix(2,10,10)

library(Matrix)
a <- tril(a, -1) # strict lower triangular matrix (omit diagonals)
b <- triu(b, 1) # strict upper triangular matrix
c <- a + b
c <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(c))
```

Comment: Please add a sentence on what you are doing, to help OP better understand.

Comment: Thanks, kabanus, I added some text. Hope this helps.