# Combine two data frames with identical column and rows

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, merge, rbind

My goal is to create a matrix out of two data frames. One dataframes contains the diagonal and upper triangle values, and the other dataframe contains the lower triangle values.

```
> upper.tri.matrix
      obs1   obs2   obs3   obs4    obs5   obs6   obs7   obs8    obs9  obs10  obs11
obs1    NA     NA     NA     NA  0.1621   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs2  <NA> 0.4862     NA     NA      NA   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs3  <NA>   <NA> 0.0407     NA -0.0745   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs4  <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 0.0401      NA   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs5  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  0.5878   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs6  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA> 0.2943 0.0694 0.0696  0.3702 0.0322 0.2950
obs7  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA> 0.2005 0.0070  0.1582 0.0239 0.1674
obs8  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 0.0000 -0.0143     NA     NA
obs9  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  0.6346 0.1569 0.8911
obs10 <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA> 0.1729 0.1659
obs11 <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA> 0.5925
```

And:

```
> lower.tri.matrix
         obs1   obs2    obs3   obs4    obs5    obs6   obs7   obs8   obs9  obs10  obs11
obs1       NA   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs2       NA 0.4862    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs3       NA     NA  0.0407   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs4       NA     NA      NA 0.0401    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs5   0.1156     NA  0.1017     NA  0.5878    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs6   0.1028     NA  0.3779     NA  0.6275  0.2943   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs7  -0.2033     NA -0.0596     NA  0.2551  0.2506 0.2005   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs8       NA     NA      NA     NA      NA  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
obs9   0.2446     NA      NA     NA  0.6514  0.4703 0.4141 0.0000 0.6346   <NA>   <NA>
obs10  0.6874     NA    <NA>     NA -0.0001 -0.1161 0.1105     NA 0.1674 0.1729   <NA>
obs11  0.2126   <NA>      NA     NA  0.7030  0.4632 0.4687     NA 0.9763 0.1493 0.5925
```

I am using this code:

```
matrix <- rbind(upper.tri.matrix, lower.tri.matrix[,colnames(upper.tri.matrix)]
```

But it pasts the rows of the second dataframe below the ones of the first data frame.
How can I put the two dataframes together based on row and column names?

Thanks!

Comment: If they are exactly the same shape then I would replace the <NA> with zero and sum the two matrices.

Comment: I think @user2974951's method would work, but an alternative is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031892/combine-upper-tri-and-lower-tri-matrices-into-a-single-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace lower triangular part of `df1` with that of `df2`.

```
df1[lower.tri(df1)] <- df2[lower.tri(df2)]
```

---

***Test***

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, 3, 3)) ; df1[lower.tri(df1)] <- NA
df1

#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  4  7
# 2 NA  5  8
# 3 NA NA  9

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, 3, 3)) ; df2[upper.tri(df1, diag = T)] <- NA
df2

#   X1 X2 X3
# 1 NA NA NA
# 2  2 NA NA
# 3  3  6 NA

df1[lower.tri(df1)] <- df2[lower.tri(df2)]
df1

#   X1 X2 X3
# 1  1  4  7
# 2  2  5  8
# 3  3  6  9
```